# Bring deeply placed subview to the very front

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview

I have this order of subviews:

- Parent View Controller

  - Subview 1
  - Subview 2

    - Subsubview 1
    - Subsubview 2

      - Subsubsubview 1

Now my need is to bring the very deep **Subsubsubview 1** to the very front of the screen. I looked through the documentation and `bringSubviewToFront` may not work here as it only brings the subview to front regarding to his parent. Bringing the parent(Subsubview 2) to front along with it is not an option because it needs to stay **below** Subview 2.

Reordering is almsot impossible, it is a graphics dependant order and has a lot of aniamtions binded to it.

Comment: `[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];` should do the job

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try placing it on the window itself:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview: Subsubsubview1];
```

Or use the following methods to help with reordering:

```
 insertSubview:atIndex:
 insertSubview:aboveSubview:
 insertSubview:belowSubview:
```

Comment: I am afraid of what could happen, I have collapsing animations binded to it along with its parents :(

Comment: I had to rearrange the views and I used the methods you listed, so I am just gonna mark your answer as correct in order to close this topic. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view belowSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview;
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview;
```

Definition :

Inserts a view below another view in the view hierarchy.
This method establishes a strong reference to view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.
Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Set the tag of the deeply buried subview:

`[deeplyburiedSubview setTag:USE_A_DEFINED_CONSTANT_NOT_A_MAGIC_NUMBER];`

Then in the top most view simply call:

`[topMostView bringSubviewToFront:[topMostView viewWithTag:USE_A_DEFINED_CONSTANT_NOT_A_MAGIC_NUMBER]];`

Comment: This looks very promising, let me try that out! :-)

Comment: No problem. Use of tags is a slightly contentious subject and I've heard some Apple engineers rail against them but I've found them great for things like this. YMMV :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't bring it to top though :( I set the tag, identified the view in the parent, called the function but it is not in front :/

Comment: Once you have a reference to it from the tag you could remove it from it's current superview and add it to the topmost one?

Comment: Yea, unfortunatelly that would be too risky :( but thanks for help, solved it already

Answer (score 0):

Recursive algorithm in Swift 3:

```
/// Brings deeply placed subview to the front of the parent view.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - view: Subview that should be bringed to the top.
///   - toFront: Parent view on which top should be placed the subview.
func bring(view: UIView, toFront parentView: UIView) {
    if !parentView.subviews.contains(view) {
        view.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: view)
        if let superview = view.superview {
            bring(view: superview, toFront: parentView)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
bring(view: subview2.subsubview2.subsubsubview1, toFront: parentViewController.view)
```